# Сreating a calculated field from other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a calculated amount field in the sales table that will accept the total of the items related to this order, but I ran into a problem.
"subqueries cannot be used in the generated column expression."
Please tell me how you can do this, taking into account the fact that the architecture cannot be changed.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    price decimal NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sales (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_id int NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    amount decimal GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( /* subqueris */ ) STORED
);

CREATE TABLE products_sales (
    sales_id int NOT NULL,
    product_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sales_id, product_id)
);
```

Comment: If you have to store the value, use a trigger.  If you can calculate it on the fly, then use a view.

Comment: Please share the subquery you want as computed column.

Comment: select sum(public.products.price) from products, products_sales, sales
where products.id = products_sales.product_id
  and sales.id = products_sales.sales_id;

Comment: Something like this, i`m not sure. Well, the essence is clear, when creating a table I want to make sure that the total cost from a sale is equal to the number of goods related to this sale